# edit command, arrow button not working

Tags: octave

In my current directory I have a file mini.m

```
function ret = mini(x)
  ret = x(1);
  for i = 2:length(x),
    if x(i) < ret,
      ret = x(i);
    end;
  end;
endfunction
```

Then I run

```
>> octave
>> edit mini.m
```

My arrow buttons are not working property. Instead of navigating the cursor, the arrow buttons type random characters over my file, like this.

```
OBOCCOCOCCOUnOCOCCOC ORtO= Miniddddddde
fdOCXCOCOC
  RetOOCOC# Octave 4.0.0, Sun Sep 27 01:01:33 2015 EDT <yanshen@Sams-MacBook.local>Or i = 2:length(x),
    if x(i) < ret,
      ret = x(i);
    end;
  end;
endfunction
```

Anyone has an idea of what's going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting vim as my default editor for octave by following instructions at http://wiki.octave.org/Vim.

I have Octave 4.0.0. I added the following lines to my ~/.octaverc file:

```
edit mode sync
edit home .
EDITOR('vim > /dev/tty 2>&1 < /dev/tty %s')
```